# Camel unit test case issue

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route for File transferring. In between, I have to insert to the audit table and log some minimal information. The route is working fine, but I am not able do the camel unit testing.

```
public class EobRequestTest extends CamelBlueprintTestSupport {
  @Test
  public void testRoute() throws Exception {
     MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("file:{{outBound.ftp.url}}");
     mock.expectedMessageCount(1);
     template.sendBody("file:{{intBound.ftp.url}}", getInputFile());        
     mock.assertIsSatisfied();
  }

  @Override
  public String isMockEndpoints(){
    return "*";
  }

  private File getInputFile() throws Exception {
    return FileUtils.getFile("src", "test", "resources","test.xml");
  }
}
```

Now when I run the above test case, I am getting the file mentioned, "test.xml", transferred to original output folder. Also all the db operations are executed.
I tried to use **isMockEndpointsAndSkip** instead of **isMockEndpoints** as follows.

```
@Override
 public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip(){
    return "*";
 }
```

But now it is throwing test failure

java.lang.AssertionError: mock://file:D:/output Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>

Am I missing something here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To get the MockEndpoint you need to add the "mock:" prefix.

```
MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:file:{{outBound.ftp.url}}");
```